# Typo3 broken: Frontend / Backend blank pages and no errors even after restoring backup

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I was fixing things on a not well-maintained typo3 installation and it resulted in blank pages of frontend, backend and install tool.

I wanted to fix extensions because the powermail-extension was not working anymore even after updating to latest compatible version (tried emptying cache and database compare).

I deactivated an extension "compatibility6" to see if it was interfering and since then all pages have been blank including Install Manager. I reactivated the extension via `PackageStates.php`, emptied the cache but it did not change anything. I was not able to see any error messages even though I set the parameter in `LocalConfiguration.php` which made it hard to try to find out what is wrong. Then I restored a backup using vmware. Still, backend and frontend are blank.

I am using Apache and Typo3 7.6.23.

I do not know what might be causing the problem and would like to know what else to look for?

Comment: Is your backend working? Try to access install tool and clear backend/frontend cache. Also, enable error reporting and check proper file permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have a PHP error there. The first thing would be to examine logs. If you see anything like "class not found", then your next action would be `composer dumpautoload --no-dev`.

Long time ago I had an article about blank pages in TYPO3 FE. Not up to date but still can be helpful: https://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2009/03/blank-empty-page-in-typo3.html

Comment: It took a while to do but after modifying the .htacces to set a path for the error_log, I was able to acces a log. It says: _Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The current host header value does not match the configured trusted hosts pattern!_ And it explains how to fix it. We decided to set up a new webserver for now, so I am not able to try but it seems logical. However, how did this error happen? I would like to avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry already wrote it: you have an error.
In production environment nothing is shown for not revealing any information about your system.
So the only information about the error can be found in the error log of your webserver.

**What can you do to get more information about your error?**
Enter the install tool and switch to develop mode. This will also enable deprecation logging into a file. Try to avoid filling your system with deprecation warnings by disabling deprecation logging.

Disable the default exceptionhandler by adding this to your typoscript setup:
`config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0`

Now you should see a call stack instead of blank screens.
**Be aware that this might reveal confidential information from your system.**
because of this you should use a copy of the live-system.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to access the install tool. I had to modify the error-log path on the webserver and look for PHP errors there, as mentioned in my comment above. This is useful information for error handling anyway, thanks.